# Filter SQL/Data output to be XHTML compliant

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xhtml, radgrid

I'm using the telerik radgrid export to .PDF function and am getting all kind of nasty XHTML errors as the PDF requires strict XHTML.  My initial thought was to replace common characters with XHTML:

```
(Replace(job_quota_desc, '$', '&#36;')
```

However this is a lost cause as I fix one problem and they keep popping up.  Is anyone familiar with some SQL procedure C# to parse the input and strip / replace and illegal characters or tags ?  I'm sure there must be someothers who have ran into this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having this issue the answer is simply to set htmlencode="true" property on each of your columns where you will be getting bunk data.  Simple fix ...